# Move master branch to another branch and start new master

Tags: git

I've been using master branch for development and want to clear it to only have release commits, how its meant to be used. How can I copy everything from master to a development branch then restart the master?

Comment: You can create a new branch which is inherited from master and change the default branch to new branch. If you want to change the master branch name or new branch name you can. See the link

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Create development branch from master branch and delete master branch
>   and recreate it incase if you dont want any commit history in master

Step 1 : Create development branch

```
git checkout development

git push origin development
```

Step 2 : Delete master branch (In-case master branch is protected you may not have permissions to delete it hence in settings remove protected from master branch)

```
git push origin :master
```

Step 3 : Recreate master branch and mark it as protected

```
git checkout --orphan master

git commit

git push origin master
```

Comment: I also had this problem even unprotecting master: GitLab: The default branch of a project cannot be deleted. I had to change default branch to another branch (in your example develop)

Answer (score 2):

On the master branch, checkout a new branch, which will have your dev changes if committed. Commit them if not committed. Then checkout master branch and reset to origin.

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>
git commit -m #if needed
git checkout master
git reset origin/master
```

Comment: is this the same as the other answer it looks a lot simpler

Comment: Yeah looks like it. The only difference is the other answer suggests protecting your local master branch which is cool.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to do two things:

1. Have you current `master` branch point to `dev`
2. Have an empty `master` branch.

Solution:

Rename `master` to `dev`

A good way is, as other friends mentioned. create a new branch from latest `master`, delete `master` and re-create new `master`.

`git stash //save your current changes. 
git pull // pull latest changes.
git checkout master //switch branche to master
git checkout -b dev // create new branch from master
git branch --set-upstream dev origin/dev //add tracking to new branch
git push //push new dev branch to server`

1. Have an empty `master` branch.

I think other friends understood it differently, please let me know what was helpful.

As I understand you want your `master` branch to point to your initial commit (first commit on your repository) so that you could have only release merges on your `master`

To do that you need to do three steps:

```
 
Find first commit.
Delete old `master` branch. (it easier this way)
Have new `master` from first commit.
```

Here is how, I would do it.

Find first commit.

`git log --reverse --oneline // top commit will be your first one. Copy it's hash (i.e.#1234)`

Delete old `master` branch

> remember to switch current branch to `dev`. You can not delete a branch you are on.

`git branch -d master // delete local master branch
git push origin :master //delete remote master, this will be safe as we have a copy`

Create new `master` branch from first commit. 

`git checkout -b #1234 // remember #1234 is your first commit id. 
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master //add tracking to new branch`

Please forgive my bad formatting.

Happy coding