# Archive Github Master Branch and Delete All Files in Master Branch

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to do what is described here:

[Move master branch to another branch and start new master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927623/move-master-branch-to-another-branch-and-start-new-master)

I have new "Upgraded" project files that I want to replace all the files currently in the `master` branch.

I've copied the master branch to a `archive` branch and now I need to reset / delete all the files in the master branch and then sync that with Github.

[I've tried running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927623/move-master-branch-to-another-branch-and-start-new-master):

```
git push origin :master
```

Which tries to delete the master branch but I get this message:

```
To github.com:fireflysemantics/validatorts.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:fireflysemantics/validatorts.git'
```

So do we delete the master branch and sync the deletion to Github?  Then recreate the master branch and sync the new one with the new files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a simple and straightforward way, that takes multiple steps:

- Pick or create a new branch to be used as the default.
- Use the GitHub web interface (or the API) to set this as the default branch.

You can now delete `master` as you have been attempting.  Then you can create a new `master`, and, if you wish, use the GitHub web interface (or API) to set the new `master` as the default branch.

Alternatively, you can use `git push --force origin new_master:master`.  This may or may not succeed, depending on what *push* rights *you* have, but if it does succeed, it will make GitHub use your `new_master` branch as its `master` branch.  Remember, the *names of branches* in *your* Git repository need not match the *names of branches in any other Git repository*, including the one on GitHub.

You can rename your own branches at any time.  Your branch names are *yours*.  Their branch names are *theirs*.  Just because you and they both have a branch name `xyzzy` does not mean these are the "same branch" in any useful sense: they are the same if and only if *you decree* that they are the same, otherwise they are different.  We (humans) tend to *try* to use the same names on "both sides" to maintain our sanity, of course, but that's not a requirement.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Which of these is not a requirement?  Keeping the same names, or being sane?  That's for you to decide.

Comment: I like the second option, as it would make the work flow really simple.  However when I ran: `Github/validatorts $ git push --force origin master1:master
Everything up-to-date` it said everything up to date, but the new `master1` branch did not show up on Github?  Any ideas?

Comment: "Everything up to date" means that all the commits your Git was asked to send (your `master1` commits) were already present in the target Git (over on `origin`) *and* **their** `master` already selected the same *last* commit as your `master1`. So they did not change anything in their repository. Are you sure your `master1` points to the desired last commit? (See ["Pretty Git branch graphs"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452) to see how to view your own Git's graph.) Remember that they'll be using the name `master`, which your Git will reflect in your own `origin/master`.